# Emit signal in standard python thread

Tags: python, pyqt, signals-slots

I have a threaded application where I do have a network thread. The UI-part passes a `callback` to this thread. The thread is a **normal** python thread - it's **NO** `QThread`.

Is it possible to emit PyQT Slot within this thread?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not possible to emit a PyQt signal from a python thread like this.

However, a possible solution is to use an additional object shared by
both threads, making the necessary operations to finally emit a thread-safe
PyQt signal.

Here is an implementation of a "SafeConnector" class, making use of a pair
of connected sockets and a Queue to exchange data between the two threads,
and using a QSocketNotifier to get back in Qt's loop. A QObject is used to
make it possible to emit a proper Qt signal:

```
from PyQt4 import Qt, QtCore, QtGui
import threading
import socket
import Queue
import time

# Object of this class has to be shared between
# the two threads (Python and Qt one).
# Qt thread calls 'connect',   
# Python thread calls 'emit'.
# The slot corresponding to the emitted signal
# will be called in Qt's thread.
class SafeConnector:
    def __init__(self):
        self._rsock, self._wsock = socket.socketpair()
        self._queue = Queue.Queue()
        self._qt_object = QtCore.QObject()
        self._notifier = QtCore.QSocketNotifier(self._rsock.fileno(),
                                                QtCore.QSocketNotifier.Read)
        self._notifier.activated.connect(self._recv)

    def connect(self, signal, receiver):
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self._qt_object, signal, receiver)

    # should be called by Python thread
    def emit(self, signal, args):
        self._queue.put((signal, args))
        self._wsock.send('!')

    # happens in Qt's main thread
    def _recv(self):
        self._rsock.recv(1)
        signal, args = self._queue.get()
        self._qt_object.emit(signal, args)

class PythonThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, connector, *args, **kwargs):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.connector = connector
        self.daemon = True

    def emit_signal(self):
        self.connector.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("test"), str(time.time()))

    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.emit_signal()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    mainwin = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    label = QtGui.QLabel(mainwin)
    mainwin.setCentralWidget(label)

    connector = SafeConnector()
    python_thread = PythonThread(connector)
    connector.connect(QtCore.SIGNAL("test"), label.setText)
    python_thread.start()

    mainwin.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Good work, although a lot of code is needed for that.

Comment: def emit(self, signal, args):  args should be *args

Comment: On PyQt5, `qobject_living_in_main_thread.some_signal.emit()` signal works from a background Python thread (that is not a QThread) on my Ubuntu machine (no warnings, no crashes, slots are called normally in the receiver's [main] thread). I haven't found in the documentation where the behavior is guaranteed. Google led me here.