# emitting signal when python thread finishes to close the Qt Gu that initiated the thread

Tags: python, multithreading, qt

I am trying to emit a signal when a python thread finish running so when it is done, the emtited signal close the PYQT window that started the thread.

in the code see comments.

```
import sys
import threading
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    """ docstring for MyThread
    """
    def __init__(self, job_done, settings):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()
        self._Settings = settings

    def run(self):
        while not job_done.is_set():
            if not processSetting(self._Settings):
                raise Exception("Could not process settings")
            else:
                ## Emit Signal
                pass


class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    """docstring for MyWindow"""
    def __init__(self, settings, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self._Settings = settings
        self._job_done = threading.Event()
        self._myThread = MyThread(self._job_done, self._Settings)
        ## catch the signal to close this window.

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self._myThread.isAlive():
            reply=QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, "Are you sure to quit?","Settings are getting applied !!!",QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes,QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
            if reply==QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
                event.accept()
            else:
                event.ignore()


def processSettings():
    print "processSettings() Called"
    return True

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MyWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

in the above code i want to signal when processSttingts returns True
and then MyWindow should close.

**EDIT** here is what I tried to do.

So what I am heading towards is to emit a signal if the `processSettings` returns `True` and close the `QMainWindow` `MyWindow`.
    import sys
    import threading
    from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

```
def processSettings():
    print "processSettings() Called"
    return True


class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    """ docstring for MyThread
    """
    def __init__(self, settings):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()
        self._Settings = settings
        self.signal = QtCore.SIGNAL("signal")
        self._job_done = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        # while not job_done.is_set():
        print "in thread"
        if not processSettings():
            raise Exception("Could not process settings")
        else:
            QtCore.emit(self.signal, "hi from thread")

class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    """docstring for MyWindow"""
    def __init__(self, settings, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self._Settings = settings
        self._myThread = MyThread(self._Settings)
        self._myThread.daemon = False
        self._myThread.start()
        self.connect(self._myThread, self._myThread.signal, self.testfunc)


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self._myThread.isAlive():
            reply=QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, "Are you sure to quit?","Settings are getting applied !!!",QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes,QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
            if reply==QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
                event.accept()
            else:
                event.ignore()

    def testfunc(self, sigstr):
        """ Purpose of this function is to close this window"""
        print sigstr
        self.close()



def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    settings = {'test': True}
    wind = MyWindow(settings)
    wind.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Did you try to emit a signal ? QThreads are QObjects like others. I think you get it clear, you just need to do it.

Comment: the problem is with which project I am working on I have to avoid QThreads.

Comment: Did you try to put a QObject within your Python thread, emit from this QObject and connect to this QObject from MyWindow ?

Comment: could you please show what you are trying to say I have updated with an edit above..

instead of `QtCore` i tried using self but that won't make sense since `threading.Thread` object doesn't have emit function, so now all I need is to emit the `QtSignal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of the solution I proposed in the comments:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import threading
import time

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, *args)

        self.job_done = threading.Event()
        self.qt_object = QtCore.QObject()

    def end_job(self):
        self.job_done.set()

    def run(self):
        while not self.job_done.is_set():
            time.sleep(1)

        QtCore.QObject.emit(self.qt_object, QtCore.SIGNAL("job_done"))


th = MyThread()
th.start()

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

w = QtGui.QWidget()
btn = QtGui.QPushButton('click me to exit', w)
QtGui.QVBoxLayout(w)
w.layout().addWidget(btn)

def btn_clicked():
    th.end_job()

QtCore.QObject.connect(btn, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), btn_clicked)

QtCore.QObject.connect(th.qt_object, QtCore.SIGNAL("job_done"), w.close)

w.show()

app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that the solution is thread-safe, and directly connecting signals emitted from a python thread to a slot in QT thread is not thread safe.  The SafeConnector class proposed by mguijarr in his answer to "[Emit signal in standard python thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078249/emit-signal-in-standard-python-thread)" may be useful.  I successfully use a modified version of his solution that uses a pipe rather than a socket:

```
class SafeConnector(object):
    """Share between Python thread and a Qt thread.

    Qt thread calls :meth:`connect` and the python thread calls :meth:`emit`.
    The slot corresponding to the emitted signal will be called in Qt's
    thread.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self._fh_read, self._fh_write = os.pipe()
        self._queue = Queue.Queue()
        self._qt_object = QtCore.QObject()
        self._notifier = QtCore.QSocketNotifier(self._fh_read,
                                                QtCore.QSocketNotifier.Read)
        self._notifier.activated.connect(self._recv)

    def close(self):
        del self._qt_object
        self._qt_object = None
        os.close(self._fh_read)
        os.close(self._fh_write)
        self._fh_read, self._fh_write = None, None

    def connect(self, signal, receiver):
        """Connect the signal to the specified receiver slot.

        :param signal: The signal to connected.
        :param receiver: The receiver slot for the signal.
        """
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self._qt_object, signal, receiver)

    def emit(self, signal, *args):
        """Emit a Qt signal from a python thread.

        All remaning args are passed to the signal.

        :param signal: The Qt signal to emit.
        """
        self._queue.put((signal, args))
        os.write(self._fh_write, '!')

    def _recv(self):
        """Receive the signal from the Queue in Qt's main thread."""
        os.read(self._fh_read, 1)
        signal, args = self._queue.get()
        self._qt_object.emit(signal, *args)
```

The example from mguijarr's post is valid using either implementation.